# VS2008 deployment project. Change UpgradeCode for every build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-installer

Is it possible to setup vdproj so as new UpgradeCode is generated for every new .msi?

Why I need this. We have only one deployment project, only one application. It is very convenient (for non-developing audience) to double-click .msi file and reinstall it disregarding any other application already installed. Most often it is necessary when QA guys need to install same version (but different .msi) into their system.

Thank you.

Comment: Wow! Seems like really difficult question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use some of the information in the first answer for the question [How to keep the installer’s version number in sync with the installed assemblies' version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422344/how-to-keep-the-installers-version-number-in-sync-with-the-installed-assemblies)

They reference a script at CodeProject which you could modify to do what you wanted:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/NewSetupVersion.aspx

Comment: Seems like this is what I wanted. :)