# Install project in Visual Studio how to set version from main exe

Tags: c#, installation, version

I have a standard out of the box install project, that installs one program (c#) and a dll. I want the installer version to be set from the main program itself, rather than entering it into the properties box of the install project.

Is it possible to do this, or do I need a stronger install program than the standard one?

Comment: Installer version or application version info

Comment: Mark, that is the question, right? I want to use the application version info as the installer version. I want them to be the same, and the application version to be the source.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer of this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422344/how-to-keep-the-installers-version-number-in-sync-with-the-installed-assemblies)

Comment: Mark if you put this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: You probably should just give the referenced answer an uptick, He was the one that did the work. I just searched.

Answer (score 0):

Try Click Once Deployment: [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but it is in a strictly controlled corporate environment and they insist on MSIs.

Comment: Click one deploment install new version of application on the client everytime the application is updated.